# What is the standard foundation for category theory?

Tags: category-theory, foundations

Reference : http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279

For 2 days, I have searched what possible foundations for category theory are there and I think the reference link explains possible foundations nicely. The paper shows that each foundation has advantage and disadvantage over others, but the paper says nothing about disadvantage of Inaccessible cardinal foundation, so I guess it is the best one.

What is the standard set-theoretic foundation for Category theory? Inaccessible cardinal approach?

If so, when we say "set", do we mean only "small sets" in the language of category theory? That is, are we dropping off "large sets" and consider only "small sets"?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard. This will vary from $\sf ZFC$ or $\sf NBG$ for small categories; to weak universes; to universes; to using type theoretic foundations; to assuming category theory as a foundation for itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you think it is okay to choose exactly one of those posibillities as one's foundation for category? (If one is not that interested in category itself, but in applications to "set-theoretic mathematics")

Comment: I'm a utilitarian. Use whichever gives the most flexibility and power for a given argument, and if possible outline the transfer of the argument to weaker systems as well. I also don't really work with categories, so my answer is rather irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with Asaf, there is no standard (this also explains the existence of such papers by Mike).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I want to know your opinion about whether the set-theoretic foundation(grothendieck universe) is not sufficient in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Usually it is sufficient, but sometimes we even need two (or more) nested universes. This is really just a technical device and makes the theory more convenient to write down. Every *concrete* statement will be provable in ZF right away.